# How to construct a new Word Doc in VBA line by line without screen flashes

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code works to build a new Word doc line by line, but the screen flashes each time a line is inserted.  I am basically generating a new document mostly comprised of a sorted list of snippets of text that I extract from an active document.  I have a program (more complicated than the below, but with the same flashing problem) that produces a fine result, but I do not want to suffer a seizure or induce seizures in others.  Is there a way to automate insertions into a document that is not the active window, or to display only the final result and not each step as it is completed?

Inserting the whole list as one long string variable, even if I can use newline characters to insert paragraphs, will not quite do the trick as the actual document I am building has various formatting changes for which automating Word seems like the most convenient option.

```
Sub HelloWorlds()

dim i As Long

Documents.Add DocumentType:=wdNewBlankDocument ' opens and puts cursor in a new doc

For i = 1 to 8

Selection.InsertAfter ("Hello World" & i)
Selection.InsertParagraphAfter

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: try adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the `For` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pupa Rebbe's solution of adding

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

before the "For" loop works, thanks!  A cursor flashes a little bit as it is working, but it's nothing like the annoying strobe effect I was getting.